# Execute a smart contract from outsite the block chain

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts

I have private-permissioned blockchain and I need to allow people from the external world outside the chain to be able to query some specific parts of the data stored in the chain. Is it possible and what is the best method to do that? I am thinking about creating a smart contract with public functions with anyone can execute the contract that the public function will query the chain and return the results. Is it a doable thing?

Comment: why wouldn't it be doable? what are your concerns?

Comment: Can you kindly point such example or code piece

Comment: this question is too broad to be able to help you, you need to give more context and some code that you have tried.

Comment: are you using Hyperledger Burrow or something like that?

Comment: @Malintha The question is very broad to answer, usually *best methods* depends on some sort of things. However, what you are trying to achieve is doable if speed of transactions is faster.